# Why can not add program argument to the junit configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit, spring-test

I have created a test and want to run my test. I use the latest version of IntelliJ with spring boot 2 and spring test starter.

I should be able to pas the program argument to the application. when I set up a JUnit run configuration the program arguments field is gray and disabled.

because of this, my test fails.
**Does anybody have any idea why this field is disabled?**

[image]

Comment: I think it actual only for running applications and passing arguments in `main` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only supported scenario to create a configuration with an argument is from displayed parametrized test results run previously.

Unit tests are executed via the test runner framework, your main method is not called at all by JUnit, therefore you can't supply program arguments this way.

To pass the arguments to the application via its main method you have to use Application Run/Debug configuration type in IDEA.

If you want to pass parameters to the unit tests, consider using VM Options field, like `-Dparam=value` and in the test method you can read it with `String value = System.getProperty("param");`